# AVPlayer taking time to play MP3

Tags: ios, avplayer, audio-streaming

I working on music player app, which plays audio from URL like gaana.com

for this I am using Jukebox library, it is internally using AVPlayer
https://github.com/teodorpatras/Jukebox

The problem I am facing is player takes too much time to play, it buffers and prepare all streaming data before play. What I see in other apps like gaana and Saavn they play music and buffer simultaneously.

I know there is a method **playImmediately** that starts playing when having sufficient data, but In my case music starts playing and stop after 1 sec and again takes too much time until whole audio suffers.

Can anyone help me out in this, I want to start the audio when there is enough data buffered and buffering of remaining data simultaneously.